# Problem transpiling Material JS in Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, babel-loader, transpiler

I am trying to transpile the Material JS in a Laravel set up. What is the best way to set up babel-loader for transpiling in Laravel Mix's `webpack.mix.js` file?

I currently have my `webpack.mix.js` file set up as such:

```
mix.js('resources/js/*.js', 'public/js', {
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {presets: ['env']}
})
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {
     includePaths: ['node_modules']
   });
```

Nonetheless, I still get the following error: 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` this is in reference to `login.js`: line 1.

Edit: `login.js` contains the following:

```
import {MDCRipple} from '@material/ripple';
import {MDCTextField} from '@material/textfield';

const username = new MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.username'));
const password = new MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.password'));

new MDCRipple(document.querySelector('.cancel'));
new MDCRipple(document.querySelector('.next'));
```

Comment: there has to be more on the error message, like what line

Comment: The error message references line 1 of the js file.

Comment: your mix file looks good for me. Please try to delete all the node_modules folder and run npm install again. If the problem persists after that, you should check the js files in the resources/js/ because there is a probability the errors is in there. 

Another thing about the error message, is it just that? no error trace to other files?

Comment: @RizkyArlin, I deleted the node_modules folder and ran npm install again, but it is still not working. I've updated my original post to include information about the file being referenced (login.js)-- sorry, I should've included that before. Thank you for your help!